# How to make Bootstrap 5 rows have the same spacing as bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, rows, bootstrap-5

I understand that Bootstrap 5 uses gutters for row spacing but if I have (lots of) existing html that I want to use without modifying, is there a way to rig the site.css so that the row spacing looks similar?

Answer (score 0):

Was `30px` spacing between 2 columns row in bootstrap 4. and, have `1.5rem` spacing between 2 columns row in bootstrap 5. that means, `24px` in bootstrap 5. So, if you want to `30px` there. So You can use below simple css code in your stylesheet css file.

```
.row {
  --bs-gutter-x: 1.875rem;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately that didn't seem to have any affect. I even tried it in a <style> tag at the page level.